# Identify peach tree

Tags: fruit-trees

I have recently moved and in the garden of the new house there is a small peach tree.

There are quite a lof of fruits, smaller than those in the shop, with a velvety skin. I tried a couple last month and they didn't taste much, probably because they were not ripe? They are still mostly yellow, with spots of pink.

How can identify the tree? Are the fruits edible?

Here are a couple of pictures:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most peach trees look pretty similar and there are a lot of kinds of peaches. I don't think you're ever going to know for sure just by looking at it, tasting it, etc. If you can dig into the history of the plant to find actual records, then, yeah, you could. A genetic test (if you could manage to get one) to compare it to the tests of others, would likely yield results, but that would be super expensive and maybe not available for you.

However, you can make some guesses, and narrow down the list considerably. For instance, some peaches are freestone and some are clingstone. So, you can cut the possibilities in half by figuring out which one yours is.

After that, you might try comparing the taste, texture, size, juiciness of your peaches with known varieties grown in similar conditions.

At the end of the day, though, it's still an unknown variety. So, if you find one that seems to be an exact match, you shouldn't claim that that's what it is. Maybe say it's similar to that instead.

It does appear to be a peach, so the fruits should be edible when they're ripe. They'll probably soften and smell quite good when they get ripe. Peaches don't ripen early in the season, but it's getting close to the time when they should start to ripen, if you're in an area like mine. Unripe peaches are pretty hard; so, if they're soft already, where if you squeeze them they'll break and ooze juice, then they're probably already ripe. Ripe peaches can be firm or soft depending, but unripe ones should reliably be firm (and less fragrant).

Both ripe and unripe peaches have that red blush, but riper ones are less green in the areas where the blush isn't.

If possible, I would suggest asking the previous owner if they know the variety name, and where they got it. Maybe they told your neighbors at some point, too.

I'm guessing blacksmith37 is right about it being seed-grown by the look of it, but I would give it a real chance before you think it's sub-par (being a child of an unstable tree doesn't automatically mean it's less than the parent; and I believe stable peaches do exist). Try fertilizing it during the growing season next year. Make sure it has enough sun to help it get sweeter.

Comment: I've seen several sources claiming that *most* peaches come relatively true-to-type when seed-grown.

Answer (score 1):

From the location photo it does not look like it was a young tree that was planted. Likely a volunteer from a random pit, so not a specific variety. Edible but may or may not be desirable fruit. Peach trees grow fairly fast so I suggest planting a variety you want in a convenient location.